# How to only wait for a new Socket with ServerSocket without usage of an accept()?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, serversocket

I have a basic server thread in which I accept sockets with the accept () function. For a certain period of time, I would need to avoid connecting new sockets. I want to do this from another thread by telling the server thread to not make new connections.

```
public class ServerThread extends Thread {
    private boolean running = false;

    private final ConnectionManager connectionManager;

    private final AtomicBoolean acceptNewConnections;

    ServerThread(ConnectionManager connectionManager, int port) {
        super("ServerThread");

        this.connectionManager = connectionManager;
        this.port = port;

        this.acceptNewConnections = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }

    // This is called from other threads
    public void setAcceptNewConnections(boolean value) {
        acceptNewConnections.set(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void shutdown() {
        acceptNewConnections.set(false);

        running = false;

        try {
            join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        running = true;

        connectionManager.serverThreadStart();

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {
            acceptNewConnections.set(true);

            while (running) {
                try {
                    if (acceptNewConnections.get()) {
                        final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        if (acceptNewConnections.get()) connectionManager.addClient(socket);
                        else socket.close();
                    } else {
                        try {Thread.sleep(10);} catch(InterruptedException e){}
                    }
                } catch (SocketTimeoutException ignored) {
                    //
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //
        }

        connectionManager.serverThreadStop();
    }
}
```

My questions are:

Is there a way to interrupt waiting for a new socket while waiting?

Is there a way to wait for a new socket, but would accept it as needed after waiting for it, not wait and accept it in one command?

How can I pause the server thread while blocking new connections without using Thread.sleep() and useless overusage of cpu?

Thank you so much for help.

Comment: Suggestion: Implement these in kotlin using kotlin-coroutines, they are made for these type of tasks. They are completely non-blocking and waiting is asynchronous. And good thing is they look like normal synchronous code so easy to implement.

Comment: Use `java.nio` in non-blocking mode, and deregister your `ServerSocketChannel` during the period you don't want to accept connections. But however you do it, nothing short of closing the listening socket will prevent clients from *creating* new connections, up to the backlog limit.

Comment: From your other thread, set a 'stop' boolean, open a local connection on 127.0.0.1 so that the accept() returns.  After the accept, check the stop bool and, if set, wait on a semaphore/event/condvar until the 'other thread' signals for resumption.

Comment: what is ConnectionManager?